# CNF form of the boolean formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I have to convert this $\neg((x \to (y\to z)) \to ((x\to \neg z) \to (x \to \neg y)))$ into a CNF form.

My attempt:
\begin{align}
&\neg((x \to (y\to z)) \to ((x\to \neg z) \to (x \to \neg y))) \\
=& \neg(\neg(\neg x \lor \neg y \lor z)) \lor (\neg(\neg x \lor \neg z) \lor \neg x \lor \neg y)) \\
=& \neg((x \land y \land \neg z) \lor ((x \land z) \lor \neg x \lor \neg y)) \\
=& (\neg x \lor \neg y \lor z) \land (\neg (x \land z) \land x \land y) \\
=& (\neg x \lor \neg y \lor z) \land (\neg x \lor \neg z) \land x \land y\\
\end{align}

But this seems not so convinient for me. Could someone check it? Is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is correct, it's in CNF now, but it's not the minimal CNF, this simplify to a contrdiction.

\begin{align}
&(¬x∨¬y∨z)∧(¬x∨¬z)∧x∧y\\
\equiv&(¬x∨¬y∨z)∧y∧(¬x∨¬z)∧x\\
\equiv&((¬x∧y)∨(¬y∧y)∨(z∧y))∧((¬x∧x)∨(¬z∧x))\\
\equiv&((¬x∧y)∨\bot∨(z∧y))∧(\bot∨(¬z∧x))\\
\equiv&((¬x∧y)∨(z∧y))∧(¬z∧x)\\
\equiv&(¬x∨z)∧y∧(¬z∧x)\\
\equiv&(¬x∨z)∧¬(z\lor ¬x)∧y\\
\equiv&\bot∧y\\
\equiv&\bot
\end{align}
That $\bot$ is the minimal CNF of this expression.